# How to run Binary Files inside GoLang Program?

Tags: go

I want to execute Binary Files inside GoLang Program.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    output, _ := exec.Command("/home/user/Golang/bin/hello").Output()
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

But I get the output as: []

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the error returned from `Output`.  Also, use `fmt.Printf("%s\n", output)` to view the output as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I'm looking at the source of the `exec.Command()` it doesnt return an error but only returns `Cmd` which is struct in the package `exe`  :
[source](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go#L129)

```
....

func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd {
    cmd := &Cmd{
        Path: name,
        Args: append([]string{name}, arg...),
    }
    if filepath.Base(name) == name {
        if lp, err := LookPath(name); err != nil {
            cmd.lookPathErr = err
        } else {
            cmd.Path = lp
        }
    }
    return cmd
}

....
```

I have succesfully got the binary file running using this code :

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    command:= exec.Command("Your binary file path")

    // set var to get the output
    var out bytes.Buffer

     // set the output to our variable
     command.Stdout = &out
     err = command.Run()
     if err != nil {
         log.Println(err)
     }

    fmt.Println(out.String())
}
```

This one works for me for running a binary file that will print some random string.

Comment: Is there a better way to this? This would run as a separate job. Running it under goroutines makes it even bad. More jobs running at the same time, which will eventually use all server resources.

Comment: For me, on Windows, `exec` only works with full path to executable. E.g. `./test.bat` doesn't work.

Comment: I propose pull request on this line `err = command.Run()` to be like this `err := command.Run()` to prevent `undeclared name: err`

Answer (score 12):

I can get the output.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    output, err := exec.Command("/Users/duguying/gopath/bin/test").Output()
    if err!=nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}
```

check you binary file first or binary filepath is correcting. try to print out your error message.